# How to put databricks credentials in environment.yml

Tags: environment-variables, databricks, mlflow

I am looking for a way to put CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in environment.yml file.

Something like this -

environment.yml

```html
name: env-name
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - codecov
variables:
  CLIENT_ID: dbutils.secrets.get(scope="a", key ="SERVICE-PRINICIPAL-CLIENT-ID")
  CLIENT_SECRET: dbutils.secrets.get(scope="a", key ="SERVICE-PRINICIPAL-CLIENT-SECRET")
  TENANT_ID: "abc"
```

But this is not working and my code is not able to use these variables.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Call databricks workspace from the inside of MLflow?

Comment: I have a code repo in python which reads data from adls using pd.read_csv(out_file, index=False, storage_options={'tenant_id': TENANT_ID , 'client_id' : CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET})) which needs these environment variables